# Wait my functions finish to return my value Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

i'm blocked on my code on an async problem.
I have 3 fct, 1 is called by my component and return a value:

```
getMenu(): Observable<Menu> {
this.recupUser();
return of(this.menu);
}
```

Here i call my function recupUser() which does an http get request, and i take my data in var :

```
recupUser() {
return this.loginService.recupConnectedUser().subscribe(
  {
    next: value =>{
      this.User = value;
      this.initMenu()
    },
  }
)
```

}
My var User is used on initMenu() then i have to call this fct in my subscription to get value in User.
Then in initMenu() i do an condition :

```
initMenu() {
if (this.User.es = '04840') {
  this.menu = {
    leftMenu: [
      {title: 'Title 1', id: '1', role: '/URL1'}, 
      {title: 'Title 2', id: '2', role: '/URL2'},
    ],
    rightMenu: [
      {icon:'profile',tooltip:'Profile', id:'profile', role:'/'},
    ]
  };
} else {
  this.menu = {
    leftMenu: [
      {title: 'Title1', id: '1', role: '/URL1'}, 
    ],
    rightMenu: [
      {icon:'profile',tooltip:'Profile', id:'profile', role:'/'},
    ]
  };
```

}
}

then i initialise my menu in this last fct. i've tried may things but i don't reach to wait that all finish to return my value. i have some difficulties with the asynchrone principe so any help may be welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [rxjs operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators)

```
interface Menus {
    leftMenu: {title: string, id: string, role: string}[];
    rightMenu: {icon:string,tooltip: string, id: string, role: string}[];
}
```

in class

```
initMenu(es: string): Menus {
    return es === '04840' ?
        {
            leftMenu: [
                {title: 'Title 1', id: '1', role: '/URL1'},
                {title: 'Title 2', id: '2', role: '/URL2'},
            ],
            rightMenu: [
                {icon:'profile',tooltip:'Profile', id:'profile', role:'/'},
            ]
        } :
        {
            leftMenu: [
                {title: 'Title1', id: '1', role: '/URL1'},
            ],
        rightMenu: [
            {icon:'profile',tooltip:'Profile', id:'profile', role:'/'},
        ]
    };
}

getMenu(): Observable<Menus> {
    this.loginService.recupConnectedUser().pipe(
        map(value => {
            this.User = value;
            this.menu = this.initMenu(value.es);
            return this.menu;
       })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
I didn't realise how to use .pipe but now it's really clear.
Have a nice day ! :D